# How to prevent Windows Narrator from reading hidden HTML tags?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, narrator

I have an HTML page, with multiple hidden elements that become visible only under certain circumstances.

When I set the focus on the page wrapper (to read all the content), Windows Narrator reads all the elements, even the hidden ones.

I have tried using aria-hidden="true", CSS display: none, HTML5 hidden attribute, all are completely ignored. So far, the only mechanism that I found that works is to remove this elements from the DOM, before setting the focus on the wrapper. But it's not an ideal solution.

Comment: Its not ideal but its the only i believe.

Comment: Drop narrator, it should be your last-last option, it is like trying to get HTML5 working with IE7- you're gonna have a bad time. Grab a copy of NVDA (it is free), and see what happens. If the code works, this is a non-issue. If NVDA chokes up, we'd need to applicable code.

Comment: It's required to work on Narrator, not an option in this case :S

Comment: who says? The only time narrator is only considered to be an acceptable tool is when you're in a locked down environment, like a library. MS' own documentation even states this! Libraries and other resources cannot argue the money aspect anymore sinc NVDA 1- is free and 2- gives comparable access with JAWS. So, i would say client education outweighs implementation. The only other thing is to create a text only view

Answer (score 0):

apply `role="presentation" tabindex="-1"` to your elements that have `aria-hidden` applied.

Comment: Even adding this two attributes it still reads. You can check on the following test, just click on the content to get the focus: http://jsfiddle.net/K7vAs/4/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

Just fought with the same thing, and found out that if there's an element with `role="main"` without explicit `aria-label`/`aria-labelledby` defined, its whole content, including all the hidden elements, is added to MSAA and UIA trees which is then read out by the Narrator. Adding an explicit aria property solves the issue - but apparently also stops the Narrator from starting to read the main content automatically.

The good thing is that [AccChecker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh920985(v=vs.85).aspx) warns about these problems. Apparently better to follow its advice even though it would be nice to have that automatic reading of content.

Comment: I think your problem was the opposite. Sorry if I didn't made my point clear. The problem that I'm facing is that Narrator reads content that I don't want it to read, even if I apply aria-hidden and role="presentation", once it's wrapper gets in focus.

Comment: So, if you add an explicit `aria-label="foo"` to that hidden element, does it solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this isn't an issue anymore on MS Edge! Hurray! If the element is hidden with CSS display:none then it doesn't read it's content.