# How to prevent Windows Narrator from reading <title> text

Tags: html, windows, accessibility, wai-aria, narrator

When I set focus on the body tag, Windows narrator reads the text in  tag. How can I prevent this from happening?

I've tried aria-hidden="true", role="presentation", tabindex="-1". None of these are working.

Answer (score 2):

Appears to be an Internet Explorer bug and not a Narrator bug because I hear the same problem using NVDA with IE.  I used the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K7vAs/4/embedded/result/) example in the SO thread that @LukeT mentioned.  I don't know if that sample code is similar to yours.  Perhaps you can post your code.

From the SO thread, the code was (with minor changes):

```html
<div tabindex="0" id="page-wrapper" role="region" aria-labelledby="title1">
  <h2 id="title1">page 1</h2>
  <ul>
    <li tabindex="-1" style="display:none" presentation" aria-hidden="true">alpha</li>
    <li>beta</li>
    <li>gamma</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If I clicked or tabbed to the `<div>`, I would hear `alpha` even though it has every attribute possible to make it hidden.  I could get around the problem with various changes but since I don't know what your code looks like, I don't know which one you need.

Here's what fixed the problem (any of the following - you don't need to do them all):

1. Changed the `aria-labelledby` on the `<div>` to `aria-label` with a literal string (`<div ... aria-label="page 1">`).  That means it has duplicate text as the `<h2>`, but it worked.
2. Removed the `role` from the `<div>`
3. Added an `aria-label` to the `<h2>`, which is weird because it just duplicates what's already embedded in the `<h2>`.

If you post your code, perhaps we can find something that can work for your case.

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread [on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26849887). Obviously you have tried the above mentioned solutions, but there is an additional comment below that may help you, dealing with explicit labeling.  Also, further down in the discussion, it mentions that Microsoft Edge assists in this matter as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding, i tried the labeling too, still didn't work. I will see if Microsoft Edge can help with anything